# Power Query recognizes "general" format column data as "date" format

Tags: powerquery, dataformat

I am querying several .xlsx sheets into an appended table. These sheets are identical in headers, data format, etc.

One of the columns shared by the sheets is a calculation formatted as "general".

In all but one of the sheets, the query pulls this column in to the appended table in the "general" format. The outlying sheet recognizes this column to formatted as a "date".

I have checked the source's formatting several times, made sure the entire column was formatted to "general", tried to force the format to "general" using text-to-columns. I have tried to change the data type to "text" in the power query editor but that only returns errors.

The screen shot below shows the power query editor returning an error for each of the records in this column. The data in the error column is formatted identically to the following 3 columns (-_1,-_2, and -_3).

I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL1rV.png)

Comment: Edit your questions and paste in your code for importing one file from home...advanced editor ...    Then paste in a sample or image of your source data.  I assume there is a rogue change format in there somewhere you can erase

Comment: What happens if, in that first line that sets the data type, you change it to `any`?  What does the raw data look like for that column?  PQ sometimes guesses wrong with the data type. But you can disable the automatic detection in options, and just set them yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ron, that did the trick. I am brand new to PQ and didn't even realize that you could manually edit the query. 

Yes I just changed the data type from date to any for that column and the problem is solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.